# Django parsing until another block tag

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm learning django from a book where it has this example in custom template tags where everything inside {% upper %} and {% endupper %} becomes .upper():

books_extras.py

```
def do_upper(parser, token):
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endupper',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return UpperNode(nodelist)


class UpperNode(template.Node):
    def __init__(self, nodelist):
        self.nodelist = nodelist

    def render(self, context):
        output = self.nodelist.render(context)
        return output.upper()
```

When I'm wrapping text with `{% upper %}` and `{% endupper %}` I'm getting this error:

```
django.template.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag on line 116: 'upper'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
```

Thing is there was another example for comments like this that was working and I didn't have to register it:

```
def do_comment(parser, token):
    """Template commenter"""
    nodelist = parser.parse(('endcomment',))
    parser.delete_first_token()
    return CommentNode()


class CommentNode(template.Node):
    def render(self, context):
        return ''
```

So, why am I getting this error?

Comment: Note that [`{% comment %}`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#comment) is a built in tag, so that's why you didn't get an error when you tried to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As, the error message suggests, you either forgot to [register the tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-the-tag):

```
def do_upper(parser, token):
    ...
    return UpperNode(nodelist)
register.tag('upper', do_upper)

# alternative decorator syntax
@register.tag(name='upper')
def do_upper(parser, token):
    ...
```

Or you forgot to load it in the template

```
{% load book_extras %}
{% upper %}
text
{% endupper %}
```

Comment: it's loaded in the tamplate, the problem is with the register, if i add register.tag('do_upper', do_upper) above def do_upper(parser, token): it's giving me this SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument

Comment: actually i had to use the decorator as @register.tag(name="upper") :) it works now. thank you.